# How to typecast Date to String?

Tags: typecast

```
@isTest
public class Listexamples {
   @isTest static public void main(){
       List<String> name = new List<String>();
       name.add('Ranjit');
       name.add('Shantanu');
       name.add('Vineeth');
       name.add('Upendra');
       System.debug('Names in the list are '+name);
       Set<integer> marks = new Set<integer>();
       marks.add(92);
       marks.add(84);
       marks.add(75);
       marks.add(89);
       System.debug('marks achived my me '+marks);
       Map<string,integer> book_index = new Map<string,integer>();
       book_index.put('Relationships',7);
       book_index.put('Validationrules',15);
       book_index.put('pagelayouts ',20);
       book_index.put('recordtypes',35);
       book_index.put('dependencys',50);
       book_index.put('triggers',89);
       System.debug('find index here '+book_index);
       List<Table> tb = new List<Table>();
       Table t = new Table();
       t.action(20);
       Student__c s = new Student__c();
       s.Name = 'saleem';
       s.Parent_Name__c  = 'sammy';
       String str = String.valueOf(DOB__c);
       s.DOB__c = '01/02/1987';
       Staff__c staff1 = new staff__c(id='a027F000003pc3bQAA');
       s.Staff__c = Staff1.Name;
       Class__c cls = new Class__c(id = 'a037F0000025Z2QQAU');
       s.Class__c = cls.Name ;
       Student__c s1 = new Student__c();
       s1.Name = 'haleem';
       s1.Parent_Name__c  = 'grammy';
       Staff__c staff2 = new Staff__c(id = 'a027F000003pc3RQAQ');
       s1.Staff__c = staff2.Name;
       Class__c cls1 = new Class__c(id = 'a037F0000025Z26QAE');
       s1.Class__c = cls1.Name;
       Staff__c st = new Staff__c();
       st.Name = 'Sabastian';
       st.Salary__c = 999;
       st.Experiance__c = 8;
       st.Qualification__c = 'B.com';
       st.Contact_Number__c = '9989898999';
       Staff__c st1 = new Staff__c();
       st1.Name = 'bhim sen bhol';
       st1.Salary__c = 999;
       st1.Experiance__c = 5;
       st1.Qualification__c = 'B.com';
       st1.Contact_Number__c = '9849849899';
       Staff__c st2 = new Staff__c();          
       st2.Name = ' Patro';
       st2.Salary__c = 999;
       st2.Experiance__c = 5;
       st2.Qualification__c = 'B.com';
       st2.Contact_Number__c = '9784563219';
       /*List<Student__c> acnt = new List<Student__c>();
       acnt.add(s);
       acnt.add(s1);*/
       List<Staff__c> stf = new List<Staff__c>(); 
       stf.add(st);
       stf.add(st1);
       stf.add(st2);
       try{           
       //insert acnt;
       insert stf;
       }           
       catch(Exception e){
           System.debug('Cant insert ');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi saleem, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [ask], and then **[edit]** your question with specific details as to what's wrong. While I do see a problem with your code, I don't know an answer I might provide would solve your problem or not. The clearer your question is, the better we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The term *cast* means to change the methods available on an object without changing the data i.e. change the type. You are looking to *convert* the data as well as change the type and so will need to use a method typically named `valueOf` or `parse`. Which method depends on the formatting of the string as there are many ways to represent a date with things like the separator character varying.